# How can I return the first non-empty string?

Tags: rust

The following Python code returns the first non-empty string (in this example, the content of `bar`):

```py
foo = ""
bar = "hello"
foo or bar # returns "hello"
```

How do I write it in Rust? I tried with this:

```
let foo = "";
let bar = "";
foo || bar;
```

but I am getting this

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:4:5
  |
4 |     foo || bar;
  |     ^^^ expected bool, found &str
  |
  = note: expected type `bool`
             found type `&str`
```

I suppose I can't easily do what I do in Python with Rust?

Comment: What exactly does the python code do in the first place?

Comment: Why don't you just concatenate the strings?

Comment: @JanNilsFerner it returns the first non-empty string (in this example content of `bar`)
@fancyPants because sometimes `foo` may already be populated, and i want to return the content in `foo` instead

Answer (score 5):

You can also create an extension trait that will add your desired behavior:

```
trait Or: Sized {
    fn or(self, other: Self) -> Self;
}

impl<'a> Or for &'a str {
    fn or(self, other: &'a str) -> &'a str {
        if self.is_empty() { other } else { self }
    }
}
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
assert_eq!("foo".or("bar"), "foo");
assert_eq!("".or("").or("baz").or("").or("quux"), "baz");
```

If you need to make sure that the second argument is evaluated lazily you can extend the `Or` trait with the following method:

```
fn or_else<F: FnOnce() -> Self>(self, f: F) -> Self;
```

See analogous methods of `Option`: [`Option#or`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.or) and [`Option#or_else`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.or_else) for more details.

Answer (score 4):

Rust has no concept of *truthy* or *falsy* values like Python, so you cannot use `str`s as booleans. In fact, you cannot use anything but actual bools with comparison operators.

An alternative to [@Aratz's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45343541/155423) using `match` would be

```
let result = match (foo.is_empty(), bar.is_empty) {
    (true,_) => Some(foo),
    (_, true) => Some(bar),
    _ => None,
};
```

If you want this kind or functionality for multiple strings, you can use a macro:

```
macro_rules! first_nonempty {
   ( $( $string:expr),+ )=> ({
        $(
            if !$string.is_empty() {
                Some($string)
            } else
        )+
        { None }
   })
}
```

Used like this

```
let res = first_nonempty!("foo", "bar", ""); // res is Some("foo")
let res = first_nonempty!("", "bar", "baz", "quux"); // res is Some("bar")
let res = first_nonempty!(""); // res is None
```

Comment: And if OP miss the way Python works, he can put this in a macro like `str_or!(foo, bar)`.

Comment: lol, I can see if I have 3 or more then the code I need to write would be a lot more

Comment: @Jeffrey04 if you want I can write you a macro to use for unlimited strings.

Comment: it's okay I was just wondering, still learning and trying to familiarize with the language (I really hate statically typed language lol)

Comment: @Jeffrey04 Wrote it up anyways :P

Comment: @Jeffrey04 Dynamically typed languages do not have same security or fastness guarantees. They are not antithetical with statically ones, they just do not serve the same purpose.

Comment: i know (: I just don't like them (:

Comment: @Jeffrey04 if you *hate* it so much, don't use Rust! There are so many different wonderful languages out there, don't waste your time on one that causes you displeasure.

Comment: errrrrr... sometimes it is still fun to pick up a new language, isn't it?

Comment: also learning about a new language refreshes my knowledge about a language i should already be familiar with

Answer (score 4):

If you have several strings, I would use iterators;

```
let strs = ["", "foo", "bar"];
let non_empty = strs.iter().skip_while(|&x| x.is_empty()).next();

println!("{}", non_empty.unwrap_or(&""));
```

It can also go into its own function, if you're using this a lot:

```
// call as let non_empty = first_non_empty(&["", "foo", "bar"]);
fn first_non_empty<'a>(strs: &[&'a str]) -> &'a str {
    strs.iter().skip_while(|&x| x.is_empty()).next().unwrap_or(&"")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that Rust will not implicitly convert strings (or anything else) to booleans in logical expressions.

If you want to mimic Python's behavior, i.e. you want to keep strings after your boolean expression, you have to be more explicit with your code, e.g.:

```
if foo != "" {
    foo
} else if bar != "" {
    bar
} else {
    ""
}
```

Comment: I did `if foo.is_empty() { bar } else { foo }`, works, but i wonder if there's any other way that I missed in the introductory material (I am new to the language)

Comment: Not only will it not do implicit conversions here, Rust has no concept of "truthiness" like Python does, and it doesn't allow *anything* other than `bool`s to be used with logical operators.  You can't override the behaviour of those operators.